# Uploading file in MVC project under Debug forces program to exit debug mode

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, debugging, asp.net-core, file-upload

So, I create new empty/MVC project, add simple controller and view for uploading file, lauch program under the Debug mode and trying to upload file.
After selecting file (immediately, right after chosing the file in explorer!) program exits debugging and I'm getting 404 in my browser.

When lauching project without debugging everything works good, but this is not a solution... what if I need to test uploading exactly in the Debug mode?

In ASP Core I'm getting the same issue.

I've tried different variations of code, including version of A. Freeman, published in his book "Pro ASP.Net MVC 5" - nothing works.

Comment: What is your browser?Could you share steps to reproduce your problem?

Comment: Lauch program under the Debug mode and trying to upload file.After selecting file (immediately, right after chosing the file in explorer!) program exits debugging

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug of visual(I am not sure). You can fix this by change keyboard of visual studio to Visual C# 2005. You should run in Chrome, Firefox or Microsoft Edge. Others browser is not compatible.
You can find keyboard settings in Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard
Change setting to Visual C# 2005 -> Ok. Restart computer or visual studio. It will works!
[image]